# Sum $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{a^{n+1}}{n(n-1)}z^{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Given the power series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{a^{n+1}}{n(n-1)}z^{n}$ , where $a>0$, find the radius of convergence and the sum of the series.

The radius is $\frac{1}{a}$ , but what about the sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Integrate $\sum_2^\infty a^{n+1}z^{n-2}$ twice term by term. Note that we are starting from the expansion of $\frac{a^3}{1-az}$.

**Remark:** Instead of integrating twice, you might note that we are looking at 
$$\sum_2^\infty \left(\frac{a^{n+1}z^n}{n-1}-\frac{a^{n+1}z^n}{n}\right).$$

Comment: this might help you (I have not yet checked).. It worked for me so many times...